# How to change property of SlateJS node element onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slatejs

**How to change Node element property in SlateJS OnChange method?**

I have an initial element like before, notice the 'id' property? In OnChange, I want dynamically set the id property. See below for implementation, more or less just SlateJs's basic react setup

```
const initialValue: Descendant[] = [
    {
        type: 'paragraph',
        id: '',
        children: [
            {
                text:
                    'This is editable plain text, just like a <textarea>!',
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

Slate React Component

```
        <Slate
            editor={editor}
            value={textContent}
            onChange={currTextContent => {
                // Logic for newlines
                if (currTextContent.length > textContent.length) {
                    // Same example from slatejs on how to save content
                    const isAstChange = editor.operations.some(
                        op => 'set_selection' !== op.type,
                    )

                    if (isAstChange) {
                        // Set id property of new line
                        currTextContent[0].id = 'test'
                    }
                }

                settextContent(currTextContent)
            }}>
            <Editable
                placeholder="Enter some rich text…"
                spellCheck
                autoFocus
            />
        </Slate>
```

However, it says the .id property is readonly. The same story happens if I were to try and set the entire object. It's readonly. Adding new properties via currTextContent[0].newID also gives an error, object is not extensible

```
                    currTextContent[0] = {
                        type: 'paragraph',
                        id: '',
                        children: [
                            {
                                text:
                                    'This is editable plain text, just like a <textarea>!',
                            },
                        ],
                    }
```

How can I change (or add) SlateJS Node's element property in the onChange method? Is there some function to do this in the Editor class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can't actually change the nodes in onChange as they're readonly. Instead, you'll need to use the Slate API transform, to insert or add new properties like below.

```
    Transforms.setNodes(
        editor,
        {
            id: '123',
        },
        { at: [0] },
    )
```

That would insert the property, id = 123, into node[0].

Comment: Just chiming in. I don't think you would need `at` here as by default the action would take place on the selected node and with the want to be acting "onChange", I think the OP is indicating it would be the current selection? Just `Transform.setNodes(editor, { id: '123' })` would do the trick.

Comment: That works by mouse clicked pointer, so if your mouse clicked at node 5, then the editor would assume it's `at[4]`. I think it also breaks if the window isn't focused as well. Behaviour might have changed on latest though.

Comment: I'm wanting to do similar. What would be really nice is if there was a way to override / extend the actual creation of the nodes, rather that updating after the fact.

Comment: @NeilGaetanoLindberg comment was very useful. Indeed, omitting "at" helped to fix an error. Current node was selected automatically. Otherwise, it could not find where to insert